# How to include distinct count in one result set

Tags: t-sql

Is it possible to have a optimize single query statement which will return the count distinct of rows? See below:

```
create table #tbl (id int, name varchar(30))
go
INSERT INTO #tbl (id, name) values(1, 'test1')
INSERT INTO #tbl (id, name) values(2, 'test2')
INSERT INTO #tbl (id, name) values(1, 'test3')
INSERT INTO #tbl (id, name) values(1, 'test4')
INSERT INTO #tbl (id, name) values(3, 'test5')
INSERT INTO #tbl (id, name) values(1, 'test6')
INSERT INTO #tbl (id, name) values(1, 'test7')
INSERT INTO #tbl (id, name) values(2, 'test8')
INSERT INTO #tbl (id, name) values(1, 'test9')
```

I want to return a record below:

```
id      name
---     ----
3       test1
3       test2
3       test3
3       test4
3       test5
3       test6
3       test7
3       test8
3       test9
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following query would return exactly the result set specified in your question, although it isn't very efficient.

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT id) FROM #tbl), name FROM #tbl
```

I would suggest, if you require there to be only one result set, doing:

```
SELECT id, name FROM #tbl 
UNION 
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT id), NULL FROM #tbl 
ORDER BY name
```

and then trapping the row with the NULL 'name' value in the resultset.

Answer (score 1):

This is a single query, but with the example data it does do two Table Scans. Might be different on bigger / real data, I don't know

```
SELECT 
    (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(id)) FROM #tbl) id, 
    name 
FROM 
    #tbl
```

Comment: Agree with the poster that the table size would be an issue with this solution. Very effective for small datasets.